# Cannot Get Data From Nested SQL Query

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
const getCompanyShifts = (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { company_id } = req.params;
    connection.query(
      `SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE company_fk=${company_id}`,
      (err, rowss) => {
        if (!err) {
          connection.query(
            `SELECT * FROM shift WHERE isBooked=1 AND fk_job = ?`,
            [rowss.jobsID],
            (err, rows) => {
              if (err || rows.length === 0) {
                res.status(404).json({
                  success: false,
                  message: "Company Shifts Not Found!",
                  err,
                });
              } else {
                const shifts = [];
                rows.forEach((row, i) => {
                  const shift = {
                    shiftID: rows[i].shiftID,
                    shiftStartTime: rows[i].startTime,
                    shiftEndTime: rows[i].endTime,
                    shiftDate: rows[i].date,
                    isBooked: rows[i].isBooked,
                    fk_job: rows[i].fk_job,
                    fk_guard: rows[i].fk_guard,
                  };
                  shifts.push(shift);
                });
                res.status(200).json({
                  success: true,
                  message: "Successfully Retrieved Company Shifts!",
                  shifts,
                });
              }
            }
          );
        } else {
          res.status(404).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Company Jobs Not Found!",
          });
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

in the first query of the above code, i am getting all the rows from the `jobs` table. In the second nested query, i am trying to get all rows from the `shift` table for each of the `jobsID` returned from the 1st query. But i don't get any data back. The data exists and it should return data but i don't get any data back. What am i doing wrong here ? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume there is a misunderstanding on how the data gets returned and therefore how the second query would work. According to your statement:

> [...] i am getting all the rows from the jobs table. In the second nested
> query, i am trying to get all rows from the shift table for each of
> the jobsID returned from the 1st query. But i don't get any data back.

You are getting multiple rows back. So the first query works. But getting multiple rows back would result in `rowss` being an `array`. Therefore `rowss.jobsID` which is used as input for the next query isn't a correct use of an array and i expect the value of that expression to be `undefined` which will then result in the second query not returning anything.

To prove that add `console.log(rowss)` like so:

```
[...]
connection.query(
  `SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE company_fk=${company_id}`,
  (err, rowss) => {
    console.log(rowss);
[...]
```

To solve the issue, i suggest to use sql capabilities and issue a `join`. By doing so, the Database will join the two tables, then returning only rows that fulfill the `where` condition. The combined statement should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE company_fk=${company_id} LEFT JOIN shift ON shift.fk_job = jobs.jobsID WHERE isBooked=1
```

Hint: Depending on your DB schemes for `ob's`and `shift` you might need to expand the `*` and list all table names explicitly, e.g. `SELECT jobs.jobsID, jobs.<xyz>, shift.isBooked, shift.fk_job [...] FROM [...]`. If you have column with same name in both tables, you might need to resolve the conflict which is caused by the `join` while combining the columns for returning the results like so: `SELECT [...] shift.<xyz> as shift_xyz [...] FROM ...[]`.

As a plus, you also just need one SQL query instead of two.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but the issue is that for the JOIN query i need to have some way to link `shift` and `company` together. But the database doesn't allow that. This is the reason i chose to go this route. I understand that `rowss` returns array which is why i wrote the 2nd query that way. But it doesn't work. I need this method to work. Could you guide me accordingly?

Comment: Yes. Would you mind to elaborate `But the database doesn't allow that` ? You didn't mention a table with name `company` in the question. I am sure there is a way to join `jobs`, `company` and `shift` to query the data you need using a single query.

Comment: i updated the database to support this JOIN query, it works now! Thanks for the solution.